# After db upgrade getting liquibase checksum validation error

Tags: spring, postgresql, liquibase

I upgrade my PostgreSQL from version 9.6 to 12 and I'm using Liquibase 3.8.0 via Spring.

After the db upgrade when I start my app, I got the following Liquibase exception for the first changeset:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          db.liq.xml::1555784288321-4::myuser was: 8:9df75f119833ded8765efcc910ffa071 but is now: 8:57040acff0d316c100c788531a84ae8b
```

Now the current changeset is set with the `onValidationFail="MARK_RAN"` tag so it shouldn't fail but still I'm getting this exception..

```
 <changeSet author="myuser" id="1555784288321-4" onValidationFail="MARK_RAN">
```

I can solve this specific exception by setting the `<validCheckSum>` tag but I think that I will get the same exception for other changesets.
The only thing that I did was upgrade my Postgres database.

Now, is liquibase using the database's function hash? If yes then it can explain this behavior but it seems unlikely otherwise after each major upgrade or every time the db will update its hash function Liquibase will behave like this.

Comment: No. Liquibase uses an internal checksum function. Did you maybe upgrade Liquibase as well?

Comment: nope, I didnt upgrade liquibase. As u said, its more reasonable that liquibase will use an internal checksum..

Comment: I read about clearCheckSums method which should recalculate the checksums but shouldnt deploy old changesets. Is that a safe action ? I dont want to run changesets again..

Comment: Side comment - the `onValidationFail` attribute controls what Liquibase does during an update when the `dbms` attribute on a changeset doesn't match the current database. I noticed that this is missing from the Liquibase documentation. Found it in an old forum post. https://forum.liquibase.org/topic/does-onvalidationfail-work-for-checksum-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `clearCheckSums` feature. It will clear existing checksums and recalculate them without running your changeSets.

In order to run `clearCheckSums` you can use maven goal:

https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_clearchecksums.html

or Liquibase command line:

https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html

**Another option (bad one):**

you can add `<validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>` to your changeSets.

It'll solve the issue, but you'll loose control of changes inside already executed changeSets. So it's **NOT** a good thing to do.

Comment: @JeyJ I guess it's your best bet here.

Comment: I tried adding validCheckSum tag in order to see if its only 1 changeset. If it wont work I'll go with your suggestion :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Adding validCheckSum is not a good practice. You'll disable changeSet's integrity check that is being done by Liquibase

Comment: which means that if u are going to change that changeset -> liquibase will calc a different md5sum -> liquibase wont apply the changes because of the validation tag ?

Comment: Yes, liquibase won't apply changes in this case